# in R's strplit() function: What difference does adding an index value make?

Tags: r, strsplit

I'm learning R and I have the following code from an exercise where the goal is to write code that counts the number of r's that come before the first u in `rquote`.

```
rquote <- "r's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]

# Initialize rcount
rcount <- 0

# Finish the for loop
for (char in chars) {
  if (char == "r"){
      rcount = rcount + 1
  }
  if (char == "u"){
      break
  }
  
}

# Print out rcount
print(rcount)
```

My questions is: What difference does adding `[[1]]` at the end of `strsplit()` make? And why does the `for` loop stop after the first "r" is encountered when the `[[1]]` is excluded?

I understand `[[1]]` is necessary for the `for` loop to work as intended; however, `chars` is the same whether I add `[[1]]` or not, i.e.:

`chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]`
&
`chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")`
both yield:

```
>chars
 [1] "r" "'" "s" " " "i" "n" "t" "e" "r" "n" "a" "l" "s" " " "a" "r" "e" " " "i"
[20] "r" "r" "e" "f" "u" "t" "a" "b" "l" "y" " " "i" "n" "t" "r" "i" "g" "u" "i"
[39] "n" "g"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chars` is different when you use `[[1]]` or not.

When you use `[[1]]` :

```
chars1 <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]
chars1
# [1] "r" "'" "s" " " "i" "n" "t" "e" "r" "n" "a" "l" "s" " " "a" "r" "e" " " "i" "r" "r" "e"
#[23] "f" "u" "t" "a" "b" "l" "y" " " "i" "n" "t" "r" "i" "g" "u" "i" "n" "g"

length(chars1)
#[1] 40

class(chars1)
#[1] "character"
```

When you don't use `[[1]]` :

```
chars2 <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")
chars2
#[[1]] <- Don't forget this [[1]], it is important
# [1] "r" "'" "s" " " "i" "n" "t" "e" "r" "n" "a" "l" "s" " " "a" "r" "e" " " "i" "r" "r" "e"
#[23] "f" "u" "t" "a" "b" "l" "y" " " "i" "n" "t" "r" "i" "g" "u" "i" "n" "g"

length(chars2)
#[1] 1

class(chars2)
#[1] "list"
```

`strsplit` returns a list so adding `[[1]]` makes the list to character vector. When you iterate over any object you iterate over it's length which in case of `chars1` is 40 and in case of `chars2` is 1.